# Find a certain tag in html

Tags: haskell, html-parsing

I need to find a certain tag (the tag itself and its content) in html:

```
import Text.XML.Cursor
import Text.HTML.DOM (parseLBS)

page <- simpleHttp "example.com"
let cursor = fromDocument $ parseLBS page
let myTag = cursor -- find the tag <myTag myAttr="some Value">...</<myTag>
```

How do I find a tag `myTag` in the response (cursor) by its name and attribute knowing that it exists and it is single (there aren't other tags with the same name and attribute)?

update:

```
let rightElement e = (TX.elementName e == Data.String.fromString "myTag") && ((Data.String.fromString "myAttr" :: TX.Name, T.pack "some Value") `Map.member` TX.elementAttributes e)
```

error:

```
 Couldn't match type `TX.Name' with `(TX.Name, T.Text)'
    Expected type: Map.Map (TX.Name, T.Text) T.Text
      Actual type: Map.Map TX.Name T.Text
    In the return type of a call of `TX.elementAttributes'
    In the second argument of `Map.member', namely
      `TX.elementAttributes e'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is probably best accomplished with `checkNode`:

```
let rightNode n = case n of
                    NodeElement e -> (elementName e == "myTag") && (("myAttr", "some Value") `member` elementAttributes e)
                    _             -> False
let myTag = head . checkNode rightNode $ cursor -- find the tag <myTag myAttr="some Value">...</<myTag>
```

I've used `head` here since you've said you're certain of the existence and uniqueness of the node, but the more correct thing to do would be to add some kind of failure mode, maybe an Either String with a message indicating nonexistence or nonuniqueness.

EDIT: Actually, the case matching above is already wrapped up for us in the `checkElement` function:

```
let rightElement e = (elementName e == "myTag") && (("myAttr", "some Value") `member` elementAttributes e)
let myTag = head . checkElement rightElement $ cursor -- find the tag <myTag myAttr="some Value">...</<myTag>
```

EDIT2: Okay, let's expand a bit, as per request. Working from [the docs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit-0.7.0.1/docs/Text-XML-Cursor.html), the `checkElement` function has type

```
checkElement :: Boolean b => (Element -> b) -> Axis
```

where `type Axis = Cursor -> [Cursor]`. So checkElement is going to traverse the whole subtree under `cursor`, and return any elements which match the function we hand it as its first argument. In this case, that's the new function `rightElement` I've defined. This function returns True if it's the element you said you're looking for (this is, if both the tag name and attribute match), and False otherwise. 'n' and 'e' are just the argument names; that's it.

So, to sum things up in terms of types:

```
rightElement                              :: Element -> Bool
checkElement                              :: (Element -> Bool) -> Cursor -> [Cursor]
checkElement rightElement                 :: Cursor -> [Cursor]
checkElement rightElement $ cursor        :: [Cursor]
head . checkElement rightElement $ cursor :: Cursor
```

Comment: sorry, I can't understand how mine and yours solutions are related. What's is `n`? What's `e`? Could you take my code and change it appropriately? What does `rightElement` and `rightNode` stand for?

Comment: Thanks. What does `let rightElement e = ...` mean in terms of syntax, in particular `e`? I've never seen this.

Comment: `Not in scope: elementName, elementAttribute` and I didn't find them in hoogle.

Comment: `let rightElement e = ...` is just declaring a function that takes one argument. You definitely have seen that syntax before; it's no different than declaring a function at top-level.

`elementName` and `elementAttribute` are in [Text.XML](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit-0.7.0.1/docs/Text-XML.html#t:Element). Don't shy away from reading the docs.

Comment: Error: `Couldn't match expected type [([Char], [Char])]
                with actual type Map.Map TX.Name T.Text
    In the return type of a call of TX.elementAttributes'`

Comment: Ah. Apologies; there are two problems here, one of which is my fault. I was working from an old version of the docs -- in the linked version, elementAttributes returns a list, but in newer versions it returns a Map. I've changed `\`elem\`` to `\`member\`` above. The other problem is that (again, if you'll just read the docs), the tag names and elements are Names and Text, not Strings. Luckily, both of these have `IsString` instances, so if you add `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}` to the top of your module.

Comment: Also see [this](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-conduit-1.0.3.1/docs/Text-XML.html#t:Name) if it has trouble constructing the `Name` value.

You might also try [the xml package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml) instead -- seems a bit simpler to use.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help. For some reason I can't use `{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}` (it's just a syntactic sugar anyway). So I did `((T.pack "myAttr", T.pack "some value") Map.member TX.elementAttributes e)` and got the error `Couldn't match type TX.Name' with (T.Text, T.Text)'
    Expected type: Map.Map (T.Text, T.Text) T.Text
      Actual type: Map.Map TX.Name T.Text`;;;;; T stands for Text.